# Having trouble using topicMetadataRequest api to use for momitoring topic partictions in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

We are setting up kafka (v0.8) with zookeeper for our log processing.  I am trying to use APIs defined at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-TheAPIs  specifically, trying to use Metadata API to get info on all topics and partitions.  The doc says the Metadata request can be directed to any broker in the cluster.  I am not clear on how to direct the request (or how to identify one of the brokers that the request can be directed to.). The code I am writing is in Java and is for setting up a comprehensive monitoring system in place.

Does anyone have a sample code for that by any chance pls?
Can anyone provide a sample code for using any of those APIs that are for monitoring and are NOT related to consumers or producers?
I have seen code in Scala, but I don't know Scala and I have to write in Java for our shop.

Would really appreciate anything that might help.

Comment: I remember seeing the same question a couple of days ago. Have you by any chance removed a previous question and asked a new one?

Comment: No, I have not.  I don't see any other question talking about similar issue either.  Hope someone can help with using Java and querying Kafka broker for info on its topics and partitions.

Comment: sorry, then most probably it was my mistake. I will remove my comments.

Answer (score 0):

the place where you can set the broker is with the Consumer.
You can use Kafka's [SimpleConsumer Example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example) on their documentation.
Here's some sample code

```
// some sample values
String CLIENT_NAME = "_YOUR_CLIENT_NAME";
int DEFAULT_FETCH_SIZE = 300000; // 0.3 MB, default from kafka
int BUFFER_SIZE = 64 * 1024;
int CONSUMER_TIMEOUT = 5000;    

SimpleConsumer consumer = new SimpleConsumer(YOUR_HOST, YOUR_PORT, CONSUMER_TIMEOUT, BUFFER_SIZE, CLIENT_NAME);

List<String> topics = Collections.singletonList("myTopic");
TopicMetadataRequest req = new TopicMetadataRequest(topics);
kafka.javaapi.TopicMetadataResponse response = consumer.send(req);
```

Can you elaborate what kind of information you are looking for?
The information could be in TopicMetadata, PartitionMetadata, etc.